# Not loading CSS on the win server 2016

Tags: html, iis, webforms

I'm new here and I'm getting some problem that I'm not finding any solution so far, I tried to follow some tips that I found here but not luck.

Here is my problem: When I test my page on localhost everything works fine, but when I publish to my server (Win Serv 2016) and access through the server page, some CSS are not there, not loading.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just a heads up: at the moment your question is not easily answerable because it lacks important information, and is unlikely to help future viewers.

Comment: I would encourage you to check your browser's developer console to see if there are any loading errors shown there, and also ensure that any relative paths you have used are reflective of the change from your computer to your server. Beyond these recommendations, there's not much we can do without additional information from you.

Comment: As IronFlare says you could use F12 develop tool's network tag to make sure your css has load well.  Details, you could refer to this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCmb7.png). If you faced 404 error, that means there are something wrong with your css file path. If you faced 403 error, that means there are something perission issue with your IIS folder.

Comment: I found some problem related to a server, I have another server to publish and I worked well, maybe some problem on the server. I will check later, thanks for now